# Ember: The response from a findQuery must be an Array, not undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to implement search functionality by calling an API `/search?q=test`. API returns the following object:

```
{
    "categories" : 
    [
        {
            "id" : 77,
            "name" : "Animals",
            "output" : {}
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 167,
            "name" : "Fish",
            "output" : {
                "image" : {
                    "mimeType" : "image/png",
                    "path" : "/images/fish.png"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "designs" : []
    // more arrays here
}
```

Here is my Ember `search` model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  categories: DS.hasMany('category'),
  designs: DS.hasMany('design')
  // more hasMany relationships here
});
```

In `search` controller:

```
model: function (params) {
  return this.store.find('search', { q: params.q });
}
```

Getting this error "Assertion Failed: The response from a findQuery must be an Array, not undefined".

I'm new to Ember but I feel like I need to add a `search` serializer as well but not sure what to write in there. Or maybe there is something else that is causing this. It looks like to me it should be working fine but it's not. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I ended up using `ajax` call without having to rely on Ember Data and model. This is the solution I came up with:

```
model: function (params) {
  var route = this;
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    url: ENV.apiHost + '/search?q=' + params.q,
    type: 'GET'
  }).then (function(result) {
    var searchObject = Ember.Object.create({
      categories: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: Ember.A(result.categories) }),
      designs: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: Ember.A(result.designs) }),
      // more arrays here
    });

    return {
      model: searchObject
    };
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
model: function (params) {
  return this.store.find('search', { q: params.q });
}
```

This tells `ember-data` you want to find `search` objects. So it expects those in an array and not `categories`.

You can specify a path for a type using the `pathForType` function on your adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    if (type == 'category') {
      return 'search';
    }
    var decamelized = Ember.String.decamelize(type);
    return Ember.String.pluralize(decamelized);
  }
});
```

This means when you request do this: `this.store.find('category', { q: params: q });`.

It'll do a request to `/search?q=param`

This all is according to the docs

> likely to change in the future

in favour of this rfc: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/4 which will give you the ability to change a url for a specific action.

Comment: sorry I should've been more clear about what's in search object.. the search model actually has a few other arrays in it, but for simplicity I just left one in there... see my updated question

Comment: Ok, I'm officially confused. I don't understand why search should be a model. What is the ID of that one? I'm pretty sure you're misusing the model here.

Why can't you search each type individually and do a find for that?

Comment: I'm new to Ember, I thought when you make a request to API like this `this.store.find('search', { q: params.q })` you need a model for it, no? I basically have an API `/search?q=param` that returns multiple lists/arrays that already have models in my Ember app. Is there a better way to call this API endpoint in Ember and push it to the model object in `Search` route?

Answer (score 1):

With the give code, you try to find some (read: an array of) searches. This is missing in the reply, hence the error.

What you really want is

```
model: function (params) {
  return this.store.find('category', { q: params.q });
}
```

But this would lead to a request to `/categories?q=test`. If, at all, the server code and interface are controlled by yourself, change the server. If not, you could use a customized RESTAdapter (in ember-cli: `ember g adapter category`) with a custom `pathForType` method.

Comment: wait 8 hours for 2 answers in 5 mins :P

Comment: Oh, it appears that albertjan did give essentially the same answer at essentially the same time. Read those answers as complementing each other ...

Comment: sorry I should've been more clear about what's in search object.. the search model actually has a few other arrays in it, but for simplicity I just left one in there... see my updated question